# How to get one element to directly stack each other without using margin property?

Tags: html, css

Currently, element Three goes directly below element One, but I want it so Three goes right below Two. If I add `margin-left:30px` to block class, it Three goes directly below Two, but I would like to know if there is a way to get this done without using margin-left property? Here is the link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-smoke-l561y?file=/index.html

```css
span.block {
  display: block;
}

span.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<span>One</span>
<span>Two</span>
<span class="block">Three</span>
```

So now if I run the code above then I get this result below

```
One Two
Three
```

But I would like to update it so I get the result below without using margin.

```
One Two
    Three
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2):

Your example is confusing, as you provide CSS with an element `span.container` that is never used. Plus, `<span>` is an inline-element that you force to become a block-element. It would be better to just use a `<div>` then. It is the "block-element counterpart" of a `span`, a simple wrapper-element without semantics.

One way would be to use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), like Evren already showed. Another way would be to use [CSS-Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). It's very easy to define columns there.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b"
    "c d ";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)
}

.container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.container > div.my-block {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.15);
  grid-area: d;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div class="my-block">Three</div>
</div>
```

Or maybe you just want to show some data? Then even a simple table would be a valid choice:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you provide additional context and describe exactly what your situation is, people here on SO can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different approach that you can use. That's an example with flexbox

```css
    div {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
   
    span { 
      width: 50%;
      background: blue;  
 }
```

```html
    <div>
     <span>One</span>
     <span>Two</span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <span >Three</span>
    </div>
```